# Use cases to measure an ORM framework?

Tags: nhibernate, entity-framework, orm

I want to compare Entity framework 4 and NHibernate, but it would be hard to do so unless I develop two real project using both of them. Even I do have two project, It's not likely that I would be able to use most of the common features of the two frameworks. So I'm wondering if there's a set of sample domain models, and if I implement their use cases, I would be able to demonstrate the common features of an ORM framework.

In addition to comparing them, I also want to use those sample models and use cases as a means of learning the frameworks myself. Moreover, they can be used to measure the usability, performance, any other aspects of an ORM framework. So instead of telling me how good the framework is, please let me know how I can discover the pros/cons myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 vs NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I'm more of hoping to use and compare the features myself.

Comment: Fork an existing project (twice) and see what it takes to incorporate each ORM.

Comment: Jay: Thanks. but my project only demonstrates a small subset of common features of an ORM.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little unclear exactly what you're asking here, but you could use the [AdventureWorks sample](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) database schema as a sample domain model.

With it you could then generate two separate data access models (one for EFv4 and one for nHibernate) and test each according to your own specification (performance, ease-of-use, interoperability with Web Services, etc etc).

There are plenty of samples and use cases built around AdventureWorks if you wanted to simulate a potential real work usage scenario for both ORMs e.g. with SharePoint ([MOSS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AdventureWorksSite)),  and with WPF ([WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AdventureWorks_Part1.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

http://ormbattle.net/ - there is a comparision of ORM's with source code and etc. Actually it is performance comparizon, but I think it helps you

Comment: That site has a bad reputation.  It appears to have been created by an ORM vendor for competitive marketing purposes.